# why request.query is not 'any' anymore? express request.query typescript error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

after npm i this is the error that i get if i try to pass query params to a function that expects string:
Argument of type 'string | Query | (string | Query)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'Query' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

```
import express from "express";
async function getProductsImagesByShopEvent(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, 
next: express.NextFunction) {
  try {
    const params = req.query;
    if (!params || !params.shopEventId)
        throw new CustomError("params are missing in /business/getProductsImagesByShopEvent", 400, "params are missing");

    const shopEvent = new ShopEvent();
    const events = await shopEvent.getProductsImagesByShopEvent(params.shopEventId);
    res.json(events);
  }
  catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}

async getProductsImagesByShopEvent(shopEventId: string) {
}
```

the error is in params.shopEventId..
if i add:     const params = (req.query as any); it works

Answer (score 7):

This makes express more strict in typings. You have to add types.

```
const shopEventId: string = req.query.shopEventId as string
```

Comment: Express is already providing the types. The above is just telling the compiler you think know better. The type should be checked, and definitely not be cast.

Comment: something I understood long time a go is when u commit: npm install on a repo (that has package.json - all npm packages are updated to the latest minor version